# Modern HDD replacement for an old laptop

Tags: hard-disk, old-hardware-adaptation

What is the modern solution I could use in [Commodore C386SX-LT](https://oldcrap.org/2018/09/18/commodore-c386sx-lt/)? It requires selection of disk type in bios, otherwise it won't work. Max setting allows up to 63MB, so would a 64MB CF with IDE adapter work?

Comment: I can't speak for your exact computer, but if you're able to manually set CHS in your bios rather than picking a type number, there's a program called 'whatide' that can report the geometry of the hard drive / cf present. I'd expect this approach would work with a 64mb CF (or set the cylinders lower if 64mb doesn't work).

Answer (score 1):

Modern hard drives tend to list a CHS geometry of some large number of cylinders, 16 heads, 63 sectors.  I'm reading the label on an 18GB IBM Travelstar for that; as CHS only goes up to about 8GB, the listed settings wouldn't cover the entire capacity of the drive.

I think it's better to have the correct number of heads and sectors.  It may then be possible to have the operating system use a large number of cylinders than the BIOS supports, while still having compatible geometry otherwise.

Comment: Apart from the PC only being able to use about 0,35% of its capacity, how would you connect such a disk? That's the main part of the question, I guess: you can't hook up a SATA disk to this thing.

Comment: @DarkDust There are still PATA drives being sold in 2.5" form factor, including SSDs.  I have one in an old ThinkPad right now.

Answer (score 1):

CF *should* work. I guess this may help you:

1. Connect the CF to your computer, no BIOS settings needed.
2. Boot from floppy to the DOS
3. Use utilities like [WhatIDE](http://dl.mroach.com/dos/whatide/) or [IDEInfo](https://www.vogons.org/download/file.php?id=36376). They tell you how the system "see" the CF card (if so)

You can find more details [here](https://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?t=55167) or [here](https://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?t=55861).